# Convert Text representation of Hex to hex bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to convert string representations of Hex values to byte values. I am new to Python and am having trouble with this since there are not strong data types as in other languages I use. I have a Python form (created with Glade) where users enter hex values to be written to a chip's registers.

User enters 0x1D in text field, and I need to write this out via the Adafruit 232H USB/SPI dongle. Obviously 0x1D is a string. the Adafruit spi.write() throws an error: ValueError: string must be of size 1

I have tried converting the String value to an int with

```
intVal = int(label.get_text(), 0)
```

Which does return the correct integer value for the entered hex string.
converting that back to a hex value with hex(intVal) does indeed return the proper hex value, but it's as a string, again. I believe I need this as a byte value.

```
spi.write([0x1D, 0x12])
```

works, if I set those values in the python code itself, so they are clearly not strings in that case, but if I put those same values into the form, and pull them out, of course it does not.

```
l = builder.get_object("label1")
v = builder.get_object("entry1")
hex1= int(l.get_text(), 0)
hexReg= hex(hex1)
hex2= int(v.get_text(), 0)
hexVal = hex(hex2)
spi.write([hexReg, hexVal])
```

I split all that up into several lines, explicit calls, to try to debug the problem.

So how do I convert those hex strings to the raw hex values I would get by simply putting 0x1D in the code itself?

Comment: Have you tried passing `hex1` and `hex2` instead of `hexReg` and `hexVal` ?  If `spi.write([0x1D, 0x12])` works, that's equivalent to doing `spi.write([29,18])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state that `spi.write([0x1D, 0x12])` works as expected - just omit the calls to `hex` and use `spi.write([hex1, hex2])`.

`0x1D == 29` and fundamentaly the actual byte is going to look like `00011101`.